# Stop function loop without interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS function called `particleAppear` which is a loop:

```
var particles = new Array("pt0","pt1","pt2","pt3");

function particleAppear(){
    var genPoint = Math.floor(Math.random() * (720 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
    var particle = particles[Math.floor(Math.random()*particles.length)];

    $('#particles').append('<div class="'+particle+'" style="position: absolute; top: '+genPoint+'px; left: -4px"></div>');

    var rtime1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (42000 - 32000 + 1)) + 32000;
    var rtime2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (42000 - 32000 + 1)) + 32000;
    var rtime3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (42000 - 32000 + 1)) + 32000;
    var rtime4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (42000 - 32000 + 1)) + 32000;

    $('.pt0').animate({left: '+=1280px'}, rtime1, "linear",function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $('.pt1').animate({left: '+=1280px'}, rtime2, "linear",function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $('.pt2').animate({left: '+=1280px'}, rtime3, "linear",function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $('.pt3').animate({left: '+=1280px'}, rtime4, "linear",function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    var randomTimeGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1500 - 450 + 1)) + 450;
    setTimeout(particleAppear,randomTimeGen);
}
```

As you can see, the loop used is not a setInterval but a setTimeout whichs rerun the function after a random time between 450 and 1500ms. How can I stop this using JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY?

Comment: Use `clearTimeout()` under whatever event you require, or only call `settimeout` to set the next iteration when a condition is met.

Comment: One way to stop that is to control by a controller outside the recursive method. Inside the recursive method you have to put a conditional if before hit the setTimeout again. Outside the method, in the controller you can change all the time whenever you want to start or to stop the recursive method.

Comment: re: downvote, my guess would be that this is a pretty fundamental Javascript topic. A very simple search like "javascript stop timer" will present the answer almost immediately. (Note that I did not downvote, but I considered it)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks @jwatts1980. I wish that people would explain why they downvote. It does not help the OP ask better questions but instead feels really unwelcoming to new users.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out, I'll try to make a deeper search the next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the numeric id of the timeout in a variable and clear it:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(particleAppear,randomTimeGen);

clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: Note that you are actually storing the numeric id of the timeout not the timeout itself.

Comment: Should I globalize the variable timeout (since it's created in a function)? Using `window.timeout = timeout;` for example?

Comment: Lol beat me to it :) +1

Comment: @pedritoalfonso Global, no, but it should definitely be stored in a scope where it can be accessed where it needs to be accessed.

Comment: @pedritoalfonso You should declare the variable outside of your particleAppear function but not globally.

Comment: @pedritoalfonso: Not if you can avoid it. Just put it in a non-global scope that any functions that need to access it have in common. (There are only a couple of special cases where an actual global is required; best to avoid them otherwise.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `clearTimeout()`.

Create a variable outside of your function:

```
var timeout;
```

And in your function

```
timeout = setTimeout(particleAppear,randomTimeGen);
```

Elsewhere in your code you  can call:

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the function from running in the same way you might stop a function running with `setInterval`

```
var timeout;
function particleAppear(){
    /* ... */
    timeout = setTimeout(particleAppear, randomTimeGen)
}

// Somewhere else
clearInterval(timeout);
```